# How can I save a very large MATLAB sparse matrix to a text file?

Tags: matlab, interop

I have a 30000x14000 sparse matrix in MATLAB (version 7), which I need to use in another program. Calling save won't write this as ASCII (not supported). Calling `full()` on this monster results in an  `Out of Memory` error.
How do I export it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saved it as text using Java within MATLAB. 
MATLAB Code:

```
pw=java.io.PrintWriter(java.io.FileWriter('c:\\retail.txt'));
line=num2str(0:size(data,2)-1);
pw.println(line);
for index=1:length(data)
    disp(index);
    line=num2str(full(data(index,:)));
    pw.println(line);
end
pw.flush();
pw.close();
```

Here `data` is an extremely large sparse matrix.

Comment: I'm confused - why did you use java.io instead of MATLAB's built-in fopen and fprintf?

Comment: probably because i knew better java than matlab, and it was a throw away code, so it didnt need to be beautiful. it just needed to work correctly :)

Answer (score 29):

You can use find to get index & value vectors:

```
[i,j,val] = find(data)
data_dump = [i,j,val]
```

You can recreate data from data_dump with spconvert, which is meant to "Import from sparse matrix external format" (so I guess it's a good export format):

```
data = spconvert( data_dump )
```

You can save to ascii with:

```
save -ascii data.txt data_dump
```

But this dumps indices as double, you can write it out more nicely with fopen/fprintf/fclose:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt','w')
fprintf( fid,'%d %d %f\n', transpose(data_dump) )
fclose(fid)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The data_dump during the fprintf command should be transposed before using according the docs (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html). This happens because the data is written in collumn-order.

Answer (score 8):

Save the sparse matrix as a `.mat` file.  Then, in the other program, use a suitable library to read the `.mat` file.

For instance, if the other program is written in Python, you can use the `scipy.io.mio.loadmat` function, which supports sparse arrays and gives you a sparse numpy matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try partitioning it ?

I mean try calling full() on the 1000 first rows (or 5000) and then repeat the process if it works.

Comment: yes thats always an option, it will probably take a lot of time writing ascii chunks and merging them later

Answer (score 2):

Use the `find` function to get the indices of non-zero elements...

```
idcs = find(data);
vals = data(idcs);
...save the index vector and value vector in whatever format you want...
```

If you want, you can use `ind2sub` to convert the linear indices to row, column subscripts.

If you need to recreate a sparse matrix in matlab from subscripts + values, use `spconvert`.

Answer (score 1):

**dlmwrite** - Write matrix to ASCII-delimited file
Syntax

dlmwrite(filename, M)

dlmwrite(filename, M, 'D')

dlmwrite(filename, M, 'D', R, C)

dlmwrite(filename, M, 'attrib1', value1, 'attrib2', value2, ...)

dlmwrite(filename, M, '-append')

dlmwrite(filename, M, '-append', attribute-value list)

Answer (score 0):

If this is pretty much a one time deal, then I would just iterate through the matrix and write the matrix to an ASCII file by brute force, or else use @[Veynom's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217852/saving-matlab-sparse-matrix-to-text-file#217885) suggestion and call full() on a subset of rows.  It may take a while, but it will probably be done faster than it might take to learn how to read in a .mat file outside of the MATLAB environment.

If this is something you need to do on a recurring basis, then I would take @[Vebjorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217852/saving-matlab-sparse-matrix-to-text-file#217891)'s advice and use a library to read the .mat file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script:
[msm_to_mm.m](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/spconvert/comp.soft-sys.matlab/J5VmFnqMoxQ/J181s16tMKkJ), writes an MATLAB sparse matrix to an MatrixMarket file.

And This [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/spconvert/comp.soft-sys.matlab/J5VmFnqMoxQ/J181s16tMKkJ) may also be useful.