# How to save Large data without using memory

Tags: matlab, save, large-data

I used this lines in my program:

```
...
A=zeros(x,y);
save 'A.txt' A -ascii;
B=zeros(x,y+1);
save 'B.txt' B -ascii;
```

But when i run it, Memory Overflow occur and the program would be crashed. because variables `A` and `B` are very large.

I want a way like below lines that save `zeros(x,y)` to file directly instead of use memory.

```
save 'A.txt' zeros(x,y) -ascii;
```

But this not worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [MATFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) object. Then you can save the data into a variable in mat file by parts.

```
filename = 'test.mat';
matObj = matfile(filename,'Writable',true);
n = 1000;
for k=1:n
    matObj.A(k,1:n) = zeros(1,1000);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can append each element or row at a time, use for example [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) :

```
A=zeros(10,20);
fid = fopen('test.txt','w');
for ii=1:numel(A)
fprintf(fid, '%f\n', A(ii));
end  
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: in your solution, variable `A` is in the memory. i dont want to have all `A` array in the memory.

Comment: this was just a demonstration, read `fprintf` documentation to see how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is all zeros the solution is fairly trivial:

- Make a loop that prints y zeros x times.

If your matrix is not all zeros, the problem is a bit more interesting. Hopefully it is quite a sparse matrix, in which case this question has some good answers:

[How can I save a very large MATLAB sparse matrix to a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217852/how-can-i-save-a-very-large-matlab-sparse-matrix-to-a-text-file)

On a sidenote, depending on when your code jams, this may also help (and in general it is a good idea):

- Clear A before creating B

Otherwise you need twice the memory