# How to write a sparse matrix to a text file

Tags: matlab

I want to write a sparse matrix to a text file. Let's say my sparse matrix is `A`.The first row of `A` has non zero values at 10,11th index. The second row has non zero values at 1,2nd index. Then when I write the data to a text file it should look something like this

```
10 11
1 2
......
....
```

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: Are there always the same number of elements per row? If not, are there any empty rows?

Comment: Don't you care about the actual values at those entries?

Comment: @LuisMendo. No I don't care about the actual values.

Comment: @Notlikethat. The number of elements per row could be different

Answer (score 0):

First post, so not sure if posting code is allowed, but maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
[rows, cols] = size(A);
outFile = fopen('sparse.txt', 'a');
for m = 1:rows
    n = 1;
    while n <= cols
        if A(m, n) ~= 0
            fprintf(outFile, '%d ', A(m, n));
        end
        n = n+1;
    end
    fprintf(outFile, '\r\n');
end
```

Comment: This is really inefficient. My data is of size 2 million by 100 thousand. I cannot loop over each row

Comment: @user34790  How's this then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217852/how-can-i-save-a-very-large-matlab-sparse-matrix-to-a-text-file

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraints, I only really see one sensible option for the given format:

```
f = fopen('out.txt', 'w');
for ii=1:size(mat, 1)
    fprintf(f, '%u ', find(mat(ii, :));
    fprintf(f, '\n');
end
fclose(f);
```

Since the number of elements per row isn't constant, this means two things:

- We can't construct a single matrix to pass to a vectorised function, so we're stuck with some form of per-row operation.
- We also can't give `fprintf` a constant format string to write one or more whole rows in a single call, so we're stuck with multiple `fprintf` calls.

So, optimising for those constraints;

- Iterate over the rows directly - yes, we could pull out the row and column indices all at once with `find`, but then we've wasted memory effectively copying the entire dataset, and we'd *still* have to iterate over that somehow.
- Minimise the amount of high-level work - let the low-level internals of `find` and vectorised `fprintf` at least make processing a single row as quick as feasibly possible.

Sometimes a simple loop really is the best option - it's liable to be I/O-bound anyway, so the overhead of the loop itself really should be negligible compared to even the minimal number of `fprintf` calls.